# implementing answer selection using deep learning LSTM model in keras

Tags: merge, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to implement answer selection model in deep learning as shown below in keras based on [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04108.pdf) paper,

[image]

I understand implementing steps embedding, bi-LSTM and pooling in above flow. 
But how do I implement the merge function to compute the cosine similarity and loss function in keras?

loss function is defined as,

```
L= max{0,M-cosine(q,a+)+cosine(q,a-)}
```

where,

- `M` = constant margin
- `q` = question
- `a+` = correct answer
- `a-` = wrong answer

**Update 1:**
After going through few blogs, this is how I implemented.

```
#build model
input_question = Input(shape=(max_len, embedding_dim))
input_sentence = Input(shape=(max_len, embedding_dim))

question_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(64))
sentence_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(64))


encoded_question = question_lstm(input_question)
encoded_sentence = sentence_lstm(input_sentence)

cos_distance = merge([encoded_question, encoded_sentence], mode='cos', dot_axes=1)
cos_distance = Reshape((1,))(cos_distance)
cos_similarity = Lambda(lambda x: 1-x)(cos_distance)

predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(cos_similarity)


model = Model([input_question, input_sentence], [predictions])

model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

With above implementation, I am still not able to figure out how to implement hinge loss. Please help